# Xamarin.android GUI does not update after AddView

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am creating an application for Xamarin.android in c# and ran into an odd problem.
I use a wrapper class which inflates a view. After that I add the view to a linearlayout with AddView. Sometimes the gui doesn’t update for no apparent reason. The Elements aren’t added. When I call the task button (I don’t know if that’s the right name – the button left of the home button) and then navigate back to my app the elements will appear. I read somewhere that you could use Invalidate() to update the gui but that does not seem to work.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

This is my constructor of the wrapper class:

```
public BoxDisplay(MainActivity activity, Product product, ViewGroup root)
{
    View = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BoxItem, root, false);
    shelf = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Shelf);
    name = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Name);
    barcode = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Barcode);
    Stock = View.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Stock);
    typ = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.type);
    this.activity = activity;
    SetProduct(product);
    Stock.ClearFocus();
    Stock.Click += (o, arg) =>
    {
        Stock.SelectAll();
    };
    Stock.EditorAction += EditorAction;
}
```

and here I add the view long after the activity was created:

```
    private void GenerateView(List<Product> products)
    {
        var boxlist = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.BoxList);
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            var box = new BoxDisplay(this, product, boxlist);
            boxDisplays.Add(box);
            box.EnableEditText(false);
            boxlist.AddView(box.View);
            box.View.Click += (sender, e) => { box.UpdateBox(); };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code, the wrapper class and how to add the view to a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 3):

A couple of ideas more than an answer, and maybe could be bad practice, but I do not run into your issue :

- I usually add programmatically created Views in OnViewCreated (Fragment) / OnCreate(Activity)
- Make sure your LinearLayout has a parent. It must be added to a parent view (root Layout, another Layout, a scrollview, ...).
- Make sure you do not have a blocking, manually launched thread involving UI update (even through RunOnUiThread), which could be unlocked by activity recreation.
- Make sure your view isn't "flattened" by another existing one in your layout (for example having a view matching parent size in both dimensions)

Beside the fact that it won't display your layout, is your application running properly (no permanent freeze) ?